# Facebook loads 15 javascript files for 400KB

Tags: javascript, facebook, pageload

We are trying to optimize our page loading time but we have huge amounts of javascript files that are mostly from facebook. Yes, I admit we have a few perks from facebook (like button, comments..etc)
But as i understood that everything should have been minified in one file "all.js"
and this the code we have

```
(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

after checking firebug, this is what we get:
[image]

And of course removing the code, will remove these files.
Does anyone have ideas how to minimize this ?

Comment: Those scripts are loaded and used by facebook, I don't think you can do anything about it on your end except not use their widgets.

Answer (score 0):

All of those javascript files are loaded after the [DOM Ready event](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/domready.html) has fired - they won't impact on your page load time.